# Concatenating variables and strings in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to incorporate React's curly brace notation and an `href` tag? Say we have the following value in the state:

```
{this.state.id}
```

and the following HTML attributes on a tag:

```
href="#demo1"
id="demo1"
```

Is there a way I can add the `id` state to the HTML attribute to get something like this:

```
href={"#demo + {this.state.id}"}
```

Which will yield:

```
#demo1
```

Answer (score 543, accepted):

You're almost correct, just misplaced a few quotes. Wrapping the whole thing in regular quotes will literally give you the string `#demo + {this.state.id}` - you need to indicate which are variables and which are string literals. Since anything inside `{}` is an inline JSX **expression**, you can do:

```
href={"#demo" + this.state.id}
```

This will use the string literal `#demo` and concatenate it to the value of `this.state.id`. This can then be applied to all strings. Consider this:

```
var text = "world";
```

And this:

```
{"Hello " + text + " Andrew"}
```

This will yield:

```
Hello world Andrew
```

You can also use ES6 string interpolation/[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with ` (backticks) and `${expr}` (interpolated expression), which is closer to what you seem to be trying to do:

```
href={`#demo${this.state.id}`}
```

This will basically substitute the value of `this.state.id`, concatenating it to `#demo`. It is equivalent to doing: `"#demo" + this.state.id`.

Comment: Implementing the first, eslint suggested implementing your second, use string literal templates. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template

Comment: @w00ngy Yes, you should. ES2015 (which introduced templates) was just starting to get widespread adoption. Nowadays, template literals are the go to.

Answer (score 76):

the best way to concat props/variables:

```
var sample = "test";    
var result = `this is just a ${sample}`;    
//this is just a test
```

Answer (score 24):

If u want to do it in JSX

```
<button className={`tab__btn first ${props.state}`} >
    {props.text}
</button>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can simply do this..

```
 <img src={"http://img.example.com/test/" + this.props.url +"/1.jpg"}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**for Concatenating variables and strings in React with map ,
for exmple :**

```
{listOfCategories.map((Categories, key) => { return ( <a href={`#${Categories.designation}`} className="cat-link" key={key}> </div> </a> ); })}
```