# ReactJS: Have one className with binding and another className without

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How do I have a static className with a className that is dynamic?  For example, in this:
https://jsfiddle.net/uwadhwnr/112/

`<button className={this.state.color}>`, if I do `<button className="cheese {this.state.color}">`, the this.state.color won't render because it's in quotations, but I want to have both classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenating variables and strings in React](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523040/concatenating-variables-and-strings-in-react)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to add the state color as className to "cheese" then you can do it like

```
<button className={"cheese " + this.state.color}>
```

Working code

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            color: 'blue'
        };
    },
    handleClick: function(){
        if (this.state.color === 'blue'){
            this.setState({color: 'green'});
        } else {
            this.setState({color: 'blue'});
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return <button className={"cheese " + this.state.color} onClick={this.handleClick}>My background is: {this.state.color}, Click me to change</button>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uwadhwnr/113/)