# Appending a prop to an already existing attribute inline

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to **append** a property from `this.props` to an HTML element's attribute that already exists, and to do it **inline** (in the name of code-simplicity), without any variables/addons?

Something like this (but obviously this one and few other ways that I tried to append didn't work for me):

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="entity" id="ent"+{this.props.index}>bla</div>
    );
}
```

I do know that I could declare a variable before, append the prop to it and then use it as the attribute, but I have many lines like this and it will make my code bigger than I wanted it to be.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenating variables and strings in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523040/concatenating-variables-and-strings-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate attributes as you usually do with strings:

```
<div className="entity" id={"ent" + this.props.index}>bla</div>
```

or (es6 syntax)

```
<div className="entity" id={`ent${this.props.index}`}>bla</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id={"ent" + this.props.index}
```

Or using interpolation instead of string concatenation.

```
 id={`ent${this.props.index}`}
```