# add const to a string?

Tags: javascript

I just startet learning React Native an got a problem.

i fetch a php file from my server and need to add a ID parameter to the url. the ID parameter is saved in a const.

How can I add my const to the end of the fetch url?

```
const Round = 1;

return fetch('http://myurl/data.php?ID=')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenating variables and strings in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523040/concatenating-variables-and-strings-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to concatenate the `Round` variable.

```
const Round = 1;
return fetch('http://myurl/data.php?ID='+Round);
```

You may also use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
return fetch(`http://myurl/data.php?ID=${Round}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const round = 1;
return fetch(`http://myurl/data.php?ID=${round}`);
```

Note: regular variables should have lowercase names, by convention.

Answer (score 0):

Just put const variable at the end

**For Example** :

```
const Round = 1;

return fetch('http://myurl/data.php?ID='+Round)
```