# React mapped state text rendered as is

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following setup to render specific parts of the state as `{this.state.text}`. It works well enough on it's own, but not if I map it from an object. How do I get the mapped result to reference the state?

**object**

```
const data = [
  "{this.state.parameters.number} Tips to Get {this.state.parameters.goal}",
  "Your Search For {this.state.parameters.goal} Ends Here"
]
```

**state**

```
this.state = {
      parameters: {
        audience: '{Audience}',
        goal: '{Goal}',
        number: 6
      },
      subjectData: data
    }
}
```

**map**

```
const subjectLines = this.state.subjectData.map((result, index) =>
  <li key={index}>{result}</li>
)
```

The result of `map()` doesn't seem to reference the state at all.

**result**

```
{this.state.parameters.number} Tips to Get {this.state.parameters.goal}
Your Search For {this.state.parameters.goal} Ends Here
```

Whereas the expected result would be:

```
6 Tips to Get {Goal}
Your Search for {Goal} Ends Here
```

Comment: try here, this explains why this doesn't work and also a way to do this with backticks and $ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523040/concatenating-variables-and-strings-in-react

Comment: Does the `data` value comes as a `prop` to your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, React DOM **escapes any values embedded in JSX before rendering them** to prevent XSS (cross-site-scripting) attacks. Thus it ensures that you can **never inject anything that’s not explicitly written in your application**. [Check here for more details](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks)

You can change your `data` array values as below and use `Object.keys` and `reduce` to get the desired result

```
const data = [ "#number# Tips to Get #goal#", "Your Search For #goal# Ends Here" ];

....

const { parameter, subjectData } = this.state;
...

const subjectLines = subjectData.map((result, index) => <li key={index}>{Object.keys(parameter).reduce((acc, key) => acc.replace(`#${key}#`, parameter[key]), result}</li>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @prathap-reddy. How would this change if there's more than just a single level within that data though? For example:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "text" : "#number# Tips to Get #goal#",
      "types" : [ "email"]
    },
    {
      "text" : "Your Search For #goal# Ends Here",
      "types" : [ "ad", "email" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can loop through the nested object `recursively` and replace with `state` data only if you encounter `string` as a value. Alternatively, you can use libraries like `loadsh` (_get, _set methods). If you use library you need to maintain an array of object `nested path` and `value` to be replaced in a separate object like `mapping`.

Answer (score 1):

You need additional method that replaces variable names with their values.
For example,

```
function getProcessedString(s) {
  return s.replace('{this.state.parameters.number}', this.state.parameters.number).replace('{this.state.parameters.goal}', this.state.parameters.goal);
}
```

And on map,

```
const subjectLines = this.state.subjectData.map((result, index) =>
  <li key={index}>{getProcessedString(result)}</li>
)
```