# How can i hardcode the date in this function using next js

Tags: reactjs, function, date, next.js

```
export default function BudgetDate() {
  const month = month.toLocaleString("de-de", { month: "long" });
  const year = year.getFullYear();
  const day = day.toLocaleString("de-de", { day: "2-digit" });

  return (
    <div className="expense-date">
      <div className="expense-date__month"></div>
      <div className="expense-date__year"></div>
      <div className="expense-date__day"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is a component called BudgetDate im coding.
It' going to be nested in another component called BudgetBar.

```
import styles from "./BudgetBar.module.css";

export default function Budgetbar() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapperDiv}>
      <button className={styles.basicBar}>
        <div className={styles.date}>
          <div>Februar</div>
          <div>2022</div>
          <div>05</div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.item}>Sony Playstation</div>
        <div className={styles.amount}>500 Euro</div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My goal is to replace

```
<div className={styles.date}>
          <div>Februar</div>
          <div>2022</div>
          <div>05</div>
        </div>
```

with simply

```
<BudgetDate />
```

in order to use correctly formatted date.

However, my problem is, that i don't know how to write code inside the BudgetDate component. I want do hardcode the Year, the date and the month between the divs inside the BudgetDate and use the .toLocaleString methods. What is a way to archive that?

Comment: Please show us all the code. Currenlty `month`, `year` and `day` are undefined when calling those functions. Also please show desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include a variable in JSX, you need to use { variable_name } in the tags.

```
const month = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0)).toLocaleString("de-de", { month: "long" });
const year = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0)).getFullYear();
const day = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0)).toLocaleString("de-de", { day: "2-digit" });
return (
      <div className="expense-date">
      <div className="expense-date__month">{month}</div>
      <div className="expense-date__year">{year}</div>
      <div className="expense-date__day">{day}</div>
    </div>
)
```

You can add the expression directly in {} instead of using variable

Comment: Why would you do `new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0))` 3 times?

Comment: sorry, I didn't have any variables with 'month', 'year' and 'day'. so I just took a random date from web. Nothing it will matters for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd pass a [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with the desired date to the function.

Then you can paste the `toLocaleString` inside the jsx using the [`{}` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523040/concatenating-variables-and-strings-in-react):

```js
const { useState } = React;

function BudgetDate(date) {
  return (
    <div className="expense-date">
      <div className="expense-date__month">{date.toLocaleString("de-de", { month: "long" })}</div>
      <div className="expense-date__year">{date.getFullYear()}</div>
      <div className="expense-date__day">{date.toLocaleString("de-de", { day: "2-digit" })}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const Example = () => {
  
    // Today
    const date = new Date();
    
    // Hardcoded 
    //const date = new Date('2020-01-01');
    
    return (  
        <div>
            {BudgetDate(date)}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```